# Traffic light tinkercad

Tags: 555

For a project I am trying to make a traffic light circuit using two 555 IC chips. However, the output I am getting  (green > yellow > green > red > green > yellow > red) instead of the traditional green > yellow > red output. How do make it so that the output always follows the traditional green > yellow > red way?

This is the tinker cad for the circuit:

[image]

Reference for my circuit:

[image]

Thanks for the help ! (Sorry for my poor English.)

Comment: please embed the images into the post, internet links break over time.

Comment: Have you drawn a state diagram or a timing diagram for what you think it should do? Then compare that with what you have?

Comment: The second NE555 is used out of spec. It's reset input is tied to the power supply while it's VCC pin is coming from the first NE555 output. So the reset can be high while VCC is low. The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf) states that the reset pin max.voltage is VCC.

Comment: Also, even if that weren't the issue, VCC on the right 555 is simply too low voltage / high-impedance. This circuit really doesn't make that much sense, wiht the supply range given. At 9V upwards, OK, might do reliable things.